# Can I include high school info in CV for PhD application?

Tags: phd, application, cv

I'm a Master's student who is applying for Ph.D in the U.S. In my case, I graduated from high school (China), undergraduate (Canada), Master's (Korea, my home country) in all different countries. So I can speak 3 languages, and am really open-minded and independent. I want to show this experience but I know high school info is mostly excluded from CV. Should I still not write high school information?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you planning on getting your PhD in a field relating to languages?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist No. Not really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you? You can write anything you like on your CV. Whether or not you *should* is the question.

Personally I don’t think there going to be any issues with stating the name and country of your high school on your CV - but it should only take up one line maximum. I don’t think it would make provide much benefit either though (unless the country is particularly relevant to the application - like if you had gone to high school in China and were applying for a PhD about the Chinese education system, for example).

It would be beneficial to some degree to include the different languages you speak though. Again, *how* beneficial depends on the subject area, but being able to speak three languages well in impressive by anyone’s standard.

Comment: "I don’t think there going to be any issues with stating the name and country of your high school on your CV" - Grimaces in country where two of the last five (and 5 of the last 15) heads of government went to the same high school.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else said, it's ok, but no more than one line.  It is information that indicates your adaptability and resilience, and students need that to complete a PhD. The admissions committee might not even notice it, but if I saw it I'd think "hmm, interesting" and then jump to the more substantive things in your application.  I don't think it would hurt you.